# How to select specific paragraph number using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, paragraph

I want to select the second paragraph, and can I do that using JQuery but without using an id for the paragraph? Something like accessing a specific node.
I tried using $("#p[1]") or $("#p")[1] but it is not correct.
I based this logic on the var.childNodes[1]

```
<div id="info">
    <section>
        <div style="text-align: center">My Biography</div>
        <p>
            My name is JJ.
        </p>
        <p id="one">
            I moved to USA when I was 6 years old.
        </p>
        <button id="show">Show</button>
        <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    </section>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#info").ready(change1())
        $("#show").click(function () {
            $("#one").css("visibility", "visible")
        })
        $("#hide").click(function () {
            $("#one").css("visibility", "hidden")
        })
    })

</script>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/ `$("p").eq(1)`  (0-based)   `$("p")[1]` would give you DOM node rather than a jquery object, but otherwise would "select the 2nd paragraph".

Comment: Off topic: `.ready` only applies to the document there's no `$("#info").ready` event

Comment: You might also see suggestions for `:eq(n)` - it's worth observing jquery's note on [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) - *As of jQuery 3.4, the :eq pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using .eq().*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.eq` to get the `n`th `<p>` element on the entire page.

```js
$('p').eq(1) // 2nd paragraph on the page
```

You can use the regular CSS selector `nth-of-type` to get paragraph elements that are the `n`th paragraph to appear in the child list of the parent.

```js
$('p:nth-of-type(2)') 
// all paragraph elements that are the second paragraph to appear in their parent
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted to achieve.